# Is this the way to open a file using node.js and jade and read each line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am pretty new to Node.js, trying to open a file and read each line?

Below is the code, we can write in ruby(html.erb).

```
<% File.open("/home/ubuntu/test.text", "r").each_line do |line| %>
  <p><%= line %></p> 
<% end %>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do not read the file from the view! Do as hexacyanide and damphat suggests in the answers instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**handler**

*node.js is single thread so you must use async function to avoid blocking*

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    fs.readFile('readme.txt', 'utf8', function (err, content) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        res.render('view.jade', {
            lines : content.split(/\r?\n/)
        });
    });
})
```

**view.jade**

```
body
    each s in lines
        p= s
```

Answer (score 4):

You can read a file and pass it to Jade. If you were to read the file within Jade renderer, the read would have to be synchronous, thus blocking all incoming requests until the read completed. Therefore, you should read the file asynchronously:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
    res.render('file.jade', {
      lines: data.split('\n')
    });
  });
});
```

Then in Jade, you can loop the array of lines:

```
- for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
  li= lines[i]
- }
```

There's also different ways you can loop:

```
each line in lines
    li= line

- lines.forEach(function(line) {
  li= line
- })
```